# 10 fold cross validation using logspline in R

Tags: r

I would like to do 10 fold cross validation and then using MSE for model selection in R . I can divide the data into 10 groups, but I got the following error, how can I fix it?

```
   crossvalind <- function(N, kfold) { 
              len.seg <- ceiling(N/kfold) 
              incomplete <- kfold*len.seg - N 
              complete <- kfold - incomplete 
              ind <- matrix(c(sample(1:N), rep(NA, incomplete)), nrow = len.seg, byrow = TRUE) 
              cvi <- lapply(as.data.frame(ind), function(x) c(na.omit(x))) # a list 
              return(cvi) 
   }
```

I am using logspline package for estimation of a density function.

```
  library(logspline)
  x = rnorm(300, 0, 1)
  kfold <- 10 
  cvi <- crossvalind(N = 300, kfold = 10) 
  for (i in 1:length(cvi)) { 
     xc <- x[cvi[-i]]    # x in training set 
     xt <- x[cvi[i]]    # x in test set 
     fit <- logspline(xc) 
     f.pred <- dlogspline(xt, fit)
     f.true <- dnorm(xt, 0, 1) 
     mse[i] <- mean((f.true - f.pred)^2)
 } 
 Error in x[cvi[-i]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cvi` is a list object, so `cvi[-1]` and `cvi[1]` are list objects, and then you try and get `x[cvi[-1]]` which is subscripting using a list object, which doesn't make sense because list objects can be complex objects containing numbers, characters, dates and other lists.

Subscripting a list with single square brackets always returns a list. Use double square brackets to get the constituents, which in this case are vectors.

```
> cvi[1]  # this is a list with one element
$V1
 [1] 101  78 231  82 211 239  20 201 294 276 181 168 207 240  61  72 267  75 218
[20] 177 127 228  29 159 185 118 296  67  41 187

> cvi[[1]] # a length 30 vector:
 [1] 101  78 231  82 211 239  20 201 294 276 181 168 207 240  61  72 267  75 218
[20] 177 127 228  29 159 185 118 296  67  41 187
```

so you can then get those elements of `x`:

```
> x[cvi[[1]]]
 [1]  0.32751014 -1.13362827 -0.13286966  0.47774044 -0.63942372  0.37453378
 [7] -1.09954301 -0.52806368 -0.27923480 -0.43530831  1.09462984  0.38454106
[13] -0.68283862 -1.23407793  1.60511404  0.93178122  0.47314510 -0.68034783
[19]  2.13496564  1.20117869 -0.44558321 -0.94099782 -0.19366673  0.26640705
[25] -0.96841548 -1.03443796  1.24849113  0.09258465 -0.32922472  0.83169736
```

this doesn't work with negative indexes:

```
> cvi[[-1]]
Error in cvi[[-1]] : attempt to select more than one element
```

So instead of subscripting `x` with the list elements you don't want, subscript it with the negative of the indexes you do want (since you are partitioning here):

```
> x[-cvi[[1]]]
```

will return the other 270 elements. Note I've used `1` here for the first pass through your loop, replace with `i` and insert in your code.